# Position absolute caused extra white space on the end of page

Tags: html, css

This is my css which used to highlight content of page.

```
overlay {
        position: absolute;
        opacity: .3;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
}
```

[image][image]

I am using adminlte template and i am adding overlay to certain page then it caused this problem when overlay happened.

Position fixed will not causing any problem but when scrollable content the box will not stay on the dropdownlist it will scroll as well.

So, how can i fix this problem? I tried to add overflow:hidden to overlay but not working. Anyone can help? Thanks.

Function to set position

```
setPosition: function(step, targetBounds){
        // check if step has disabled the highlight:
        if (!this.stepOpts.highlight){
            return;
        }

        var margin = this.stepOpts.highlightMargin;

        var body = document.body,
            html = document.documentElement;

        var documentHeight = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );

        // top div:
        el = this.element.top;
        el.style.top = '0px';
        el.style.left = '0px';
        el.style.width = window.screen.width + 'px';
        el.style.height = targetBounds.top + utils.getScrollTop() - margin + 'px';

        // right div:
        el = this.element.right;
        el.style.top = targetBounds.top + utils.getScrollTop() - margin + 'px';
        el.style.left = targetBounds.left + targetBounds.width + utils.getScrollLeft() + margin + 'px';
        el.style.width = window.screen.width  - (targetBounds.left + targetBounds.width + utils.getScrollLeft() + margin) +  'px';
        el.style.height = targetBounds.height + margin * 2 + 'px';

        // bottom div:
        el = this.element.bottom;
        el.style.top = targetBounds.top + utils.getScrollTop() + targetBounds.height + margin + 'px';
        el.style.left = '0px';
        el.style.width = window.screen.width + 'px';
        el.style.height = documentHeight - (targetBounds.top + utils.getScrollTop() + targetBounds.height + margin) + 'px';

        // left div:
        el = this.element.left;
        el.style.top = targetBounds.top + utils.getScrollTop() + - margin + 'px';
        el.style.left = '0px';
        el.style.width = targetBounds.left + utils.getScrollLeft() - margin + 'px';
        el.style.height = targetBounds.height + margin * 2 + 'px';
    },
```

Solved by removed html.clientHeight and use min()

```
var documentHeight = Math.min( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
```

Comment: without looking at your html is hard to tell, please attach your full html and css

Comment: but there's a lot of html code.

Comment: can you attach the url of the site you are working on?

Comment: @Vincent1989 i just have the site to show overlay highlight demo...

Comment: try breaking down the exact elements of the problem into a short, self-contained, correct example and post it here. http://sscce.org/

Comment: can you just attach the part of html/css code which has the css issue.

Comment: @AbhinavJain I already attached the function code to set the, refer to the bottom div, is my documentheight correct? Because if i fix a height then white space will be reduced.

Comment: Problem solved by removed html.clientHeight and use min()